# Is it true that $(F\vee G)_\delta$ subset of hereditarily baire spaces is baire spaces?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

Let $X$ be a hereditarily Baire spaces i.e (every closed subspace of $X$ is baire space), and $Y$ be a subspace of $X$. If $Y= \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (F_i \cup G_i)$, with each $F_i$ closed in $X$ and $G_i$  open in $X$, how to prove that $Y$ is baire spaces?

I know that every dense $G_\delta$ subspace of Baire spaces is Baire spaces, but I do not know how to prove that $Y$ (in my question) is Baire spaces.

Answer (score 2):

I can only prove the claim for a perfect space $X$, that is when each closed subset $X$ is $G_\delta$ (which shows that possible counterexamples are hard  to construct). Indeed, assume that for each $F_i$  there exists a family $\{G_{i,n}\}$ of open subsets of $X$ such that $F_i=\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} G_{i,n}$. Then

$$Y= \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (F_i \cup G_i)= \bigcap_{i,n \in \mathbb{N}} G_{i,n}\cup G_i$$ is a $G_\delta$ subset of the space $X$, so it is a Baire space by the following proposition from “Baire spaces” by Haworth and McCoy (Warszawa, Panstwowe Wydawnictwo Naukowe, 1977).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still confused about how to find open set $V_i\subseteq X$ such that $F_i \cup G_i = V_i \cap (H_i).$ could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Let $X$ be a hereditarily Baire spaces. Is there any possibility that a family $\mathcal{A}=\{A \subseteq X| A \, is \, Baire \, spaces\}$ is $\sigma-$algebra?

Comment: @MaurtenErik An algebra of sets is closed with respect to taking complements, which is not typical for Baire subspaces of a (hereditarily) Baire spaces. For instance, irrationals is a Baire subspace of the reals, whereas it complement is not.

Comment: @MaurtenErik Unfortunately, I can prove only a partial case, see the update of my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer